# Fitting experimental data to a plot with different x-axis paths

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, fitting, interpolation

Given Mathematica code of eigenvalues in different variable-paths , I want to add experimental data in the path Gamma-X ; X-Gamma ; and M-Gamma .

Here is the code :

```
f[kx_, ky_] = {{368 + 68*(2.2 - Cos[kx/2]*Cos[ky/2]), -368., 0., 
    0.}, {-368.,368 + 736*(Cos[kx/2] + Cos[ky/2]) + 
    68*(2.2 - Cos[kx/2]*Cos[ky/2]), -368., 0.}, {0., -368., 
    368 + 736*(Cos[kx/2] + Cos[ky/2]) + 
    68*(2.2 - Cos[kx/2]*Cos[ky/2]), -368.}, {0., 0., -368., 
    368 + 68*(2.2 - Cos[kx/2]*Cos[ky/2])}};
    evalues[kx_, ky_] := 0.01 Eigenvalues[f[kx, ky]];
    xkData = {{0, {Pi, Pi}}, {1, {0, 0}}, {2, {Pi, Pi}}, {3, {2 Pi, 
    0}}, {4, {Pi, 0}}, {5, {0, 0}}};
    if = Interpolation[xkData, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
    P1 = Plot[{evalues @@ if[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    None}, {{{0, "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(_\)]\)"}, {1, 
    "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[CapitalGamma]\), \(_\)]\)"}, {2, 
    "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(_\)]\)"}, {3, 
    "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(M\), \(_\)]\)"}, {5, 
    "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[CapitalGamma]\), \(_\)]\)"}}, None}}, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[20, Black], PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
     ImageSize -> 800, GridLines -> {{0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, None}]
```

AN EXAMPLE OF DATA :

```
{{0.99422, 106.602}, {0.947977, 103.689}, {0.913295, 99.6117}, {0.872832, 93.7864}, {0.82659, 86.7961}, {0.780347, 82.1359}, {0.734104, 77.4757}, {0.693642, 69.9029}, {0.647399, 63.4951}, {0.601156, 56.5049}, {0.560694, 51.8447}, {0.514451, 46.0194}, {0.468208, 40.1942}, {0.427746, 36.1165}, {0.393064, 29.7087}, {0.33526, 25.0485}, {0.289017, 21.5534}}
```

This is the plot resulted from the code:
[image]
This is just an example of what I wanted. I want to add those black points (dots) in different paths(see the next figure), the problem is that when I try to add such a list of inputs {{x,y}} I get parallel black lines because the inputs are constants to the main interpolation code, i.e when I change the normal x-axis to multiple different paths I think it is causing the issue.

This is the plot I wanna see :
(NB: I added the black points using drawing tool not program)
[image]

Comment: "_Londa-X ; X-Londa ; and M-Londa_" what is _Londa_?

Comment: I meant Gamma instead of Londa, sorry!

Comment: Can you explain how the coordinates of your data relate to the coordinates of your plot?

Comment: the data are randomly chosen, just to insure the idea.